# Globally changing equation spacing

Tags: spacing, equations

I know there are questions on this topic already but none seem to fix my problem.

The current vertical spacing of my equations is much too big. I have tried using `\belowdisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` to no avail. Adding `\vspace(-5mm)` before and after equations seems to work okay, however it is very cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem} %number list package

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%equation spacing
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} 
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} 
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setenumerate{noitemsep}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:optical_efficiency}
        \eta_{o} = \rho(\tau\alpha)_{eff}\cdot \gamma_{\theta}\cdot cos\theta_{i}\cdot X_{end}
    \end{equation}

    Where \
    \begin{itemize}
    $\rho$ = specular reflectance of the reflector surface,\\
    $(\tau\alpha)_{eff}$ = effective transmittance-absorptance.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: _never_ leave a blank line before a display not only does it look like extra vertical space, it isn't even vertical space it is a one line paragraph with no text, so is not dropped at a page break. Do not leave a blank line after the equation unless the following text starts a new paragraph (which is not usually the case for `Where...` `itemize` is a list and _has_ to have each item prefixed by `\item`

Answer (score 7):

There should not normally be a need to adjust spacing manually, but there are several issues in your document:

- blank lines following a display math environment lead to excess vertical space
- each item in the `itemize`d list needs to begin with `\item`
- no need to use `\\` following an `\item`
- use `\mathrm` for the subscripts when they are not variables
- use `\cos` instead of `cos`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem} %number list package

%%equation spacing
%\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} 
%\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} 
%\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setenumerate{noitemsep}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
The equation for optical efficiency is
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:optical_efficiency}
        \eta_{o} = \rho(\tau\alpha)_{\mathrm{eff}}\cdot \gamma_{\theta}\cdot \cos\theta_{i}\cdot X_{\mathrm{end}}
\end{equation}
% ------------
where
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\rho$ = specular reflectance of the reflector surface,
    \item $(\tau\alpha)_{\mathrm{eff}} = \text{ effective transmittance-absorptance}$.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```